# Remove comma from organization author in citation

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I have an organization as author it is cited as `Organization name, .`. How do I get rid of the `,` ?

```
@Misc{caliber,
  Title                    = {{Caliber Brand Manual}},    
  Author                   = {{Caliber}},
  Note                     = {[Zugriff am 08.04.2015]},   
  Url                      = {http://issuu.com/giuliamariaferro/docs/caliber_brand_manual_-_march_2014}
}
```

Latex:

```
\usepackage[authoryear,round]{natbib}

\begin{document}
Example text stuff.\cite{caliber}

\bibliographystyle{kbib}
\bibliography{BrandManuals}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  How the citation is printed depends on the `bibliographystyle` you are using.  Please add a small sample tex document to show how you are doing this.

Comment: An alternative seems to be using `biblatex` which has many many features. You can read more about it, in a [short tutorial on github](https://github.com/johannesbottcher/HinweiseLitverzeichnisse/blob/master/Hinweise.md) and also [Modifizieren eines biblatex-Stils](http://texwelt.de/blog/modifizieren-eines-biblatex-stils/).

Comment: Where might one find a copy of the file `kbib.bst`? It doesn't appear to be a part of the CTAN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed the document style how it was, so I just changed it manually. You can open the .bbl file in latex and just make your changes there manually.

Answer (score 0):

*EDIT:* Contrary to my previous answer, this is actually a quirk of the "kbib" bibliography style that you are using -- it is unable to handle such author names.

If you switch to the "plainnat" style, for example, you will get the correct result.

Comment: Thanks! But is it possible that the other authors are still in the "surname, first name" format?